# Swift 3 overriding non-open var outside of its defining module

Tags: swift, swift3

I converted my swift 2 code into swift 3. Then I'm getting this error. Can anyone help me on this?

```
open override var formatKey: String { //overriding non-open var outside of its defining module
    get {
        if customFormatKey != nil {
            return customFormatKey!
        }
        return String(describing: type(of: self)).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the base var has to be declared 'open' for you to be able to override it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Access Control section of [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID5):

> Open access applies only to classes and class members, and it differs
>   from public access as follows:
>
> - Classes with public access, or any more restrictive access level, can
>     be subclassed only within the module where they’re defined.
> - **Class members with public access, or any more restrictive access
>     level, can be overridden by subclasses only within the module where
>     they’re defined.**
> - Open classes can be subclassed within the module where they’re
>     defined, and within any module that imports the module where they’re
>     defined.
> - Open class members can be overridden by subclasses within the module
>     where they’re defined, and within any module that imports the module
>     where they’re defined.

`open` in Swift 3 and later is the equivalent of `public` in Swift 2. For more information, see Swift Evolution proposal [SE-0117](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0117-non-public-subclassable-by-default.md).

To fix this, change the original definition of `formatKey` from `public` to `open`, and override using `override var formatKey: String { ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I did face with the same issue, then you can try to search all project - include `pods/ folder` - to make sure this `formatKey` is not `public var` somewhere in your project.